# can array values be accessed by variable variables?

Tags: php, variable-variables

I have an array which I can only access correctly via variable variables, like so:

```
$foo['bar'] = "pie";

$fixed_name_variable = "foo['bar']";

echo $$fixed_name_variable;
```

Which in theroy echo's `pie`. Except it's just not returning anything. So I need to know if this approach is actually workable or if I need a rethink on it.

Just noticed. On the second line, should the bar be in quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I hate to encourage this behaviour, you can use `eval` to achieve what you to a limited extent.

```
$foo['bar'] = "pie";
$fixed_name_variable = "foo['bar']";

$a = eval("return $$fixed_name_variable;"); 
echo $a; //outputs "pie"
```

Comment: If I could think of another solution to the problem, I would gladly take it!

Comment: Could you describe the problem a little more. A community of developers is a great place to get some advice and possibly re-evaluate a better solution.

Comment: I updated my code above to use `return` IMHO it's the best of the worst

Comment: Basically, I am taking a variable name stored in the database, and if it exists in the code, appending the value and processing it. It is part of a generic form object and brings in a stored defualt. Because of the various scope limits on the site, I can't predict which array I will be attempting to access, so I use the stored name as a variable variable to cover all possibilities.

Comment: It's too broad of an issue for any specific help. Take what you can get I guess. That's the best I got. Hope it helps.

Comment: @ xzyfer I asked the OP not one based on what I wrote for that reason. Also I have your solution 90% intergrated now, so cheers for the good help in a bad situation.

Answer (score 0):

`$foo[$key_var]` should work, unless I misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think this is possible. The only thing (obviously) possible is to use a variable index, and access `$foo[$bar]`.

However, using variable variables is usually very bad practice anyway - especially because they make debugging and automatic documentation / variable lookup so terribly difficult. It's usually best not to use them, but to use an array instead.

Comment: In this specific case, array's are not an approiate solution.